Difference in Initiating a Class
What is the difference between these two methods of initiating a new class? Both work, but I'm wondering what and why the technical difference is.
Version 1 of initiating the class.
Dim sMyClassVersion1 As New Class1()

Version 2 of initiating the class.
Dim sMyClassVersion2 As Class1 = New Class1()

Shown in a code example:
Public Class Class1
    Private MyValue As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        MyValue = 4
    End Sub

    Public Function MyFunction() As Integer
        Return MyValue * 100
    End Function
End Class

Partial Class MyWebPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

'Version 1 of initiating the class.
    Dim sMyClassVersion1 As New Class1()

'Version 2 of initiating the class.
    Dim sMyClassVersion2 As Class1 = New Class1()

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Write(sMyClassVersion1.MyFunction())
    End Sub
End Class


Dim sMyClassVersion1 As New Class1() is simply short-hand for Dim sMyClassVersion2 As Class1 = New Class1(). The practical difference might be when you do Dim role As IRole = New MarketingManager().

Why do you have a lower-case s in front of your variable names?

So no advantages/disadvantages in either? And...I usually prefix and capitalize (though not done here) my variables to make it easier for me to denote they are variables and stand out. Makes it a lot easier to transfer over, update, repeat etc.. general manage my code.

Version 1 has history in VBA-heritage VB.  In that lineage, it has an additional feature where if the instance is set to Nothing, it will re-initialize on next use.  I don't believe this persisted into .NET VB, but if it did, it will only show at points where the object is used (so more places to check disassembly).

Note that Version 2 allows declaring the variable to be a different type (base class or interface) than the object that is instantiated.

@ptownbro - Yes, there are advantages/disadvantages. Version 1 is easier to code. Version 2 allows instantiating a more derived type than the variable declaration.

Excellent. Thanks everyone!

The best way to know is to use an online tool, like sharplab.io, to see the generated code.
At the end of the day, both ways to initialize the instance produce the same code.
IL_0006: ldarg.0
IL_0007: newobj instance void Class1::.ctor()
IL_000c: stfld class Class1 MyWebPage::sMyClassVersion1

IL_0011: ldarg.0
IL_0012: newobj instance void Class1::.ctor()
IL_0017: stfld class Class1 MyWebPage::sMyClassVersion2


Or a local tool like ildasm.
